# Creating Isochrone-like polygons from a polyline network in QGIS

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I wanted to create drivetime isochrones with the GRASS v.net.iso tool and I created a network with 4 categories (each category stands for 1000m in distance). How can I create polygons from this network which looks like in the picture? I stumbled over a concave hull plugin but this just seems to work with points. A convex hull is not detailed enough.
[image]